# How to set permissions with updateTask workflow activity?

Tags: workflow, permissions

In workflow I need to reassign a task to someone else, which I do with the updateTask activity. However, here I cannot set permissions (no specialPermissions property), so the new user doesn't see the task.

I've looked on the net and didn't find anything useful. Any ideas?

Comment: I got the same problem. did you figure out this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The SPDActivities actions support changing item permissions: 
[Useful Sharepoint Designer Custom Workflow Activities - Codeplex](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/)

I haven't had to use those for tasks though, so I'm not entirely sure if this will work for you.  Are these "regular" tasks or are they workflow tasks?  In most cases workflow generated tasks cannot be re-assigned (or re-assigned easily).

Comment: Though spdactivities are indeed a great set of tools, please note that it is still an Alpha version (for two years now).
Also note that its source code has some items not correctly disposed as shown by the SPDisposeCheck tool.

Comment: these are workflow tasks. i will check this out

Comment: For workflow tasks you will need to remove the existing ones and assign new ones I believe.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of self promotion perhaps, but if you are using a SharePoint Designer workflow then you can use the [Workflow Power Pack](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/Workflow-Power-Pack-for-SharePoint/summary.aspx) to add C# or VB.net code directly to your workflow.

This makes changing permissions easy and takes away (almost any) other limitation as well.

Check out [these blog posts](http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/labels/WPP.html) for a couple of good examples.